# Issue with "definition" of pseudo algebraically closed fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, model-theory, fields, definitions

I'm having an issue with a sentence in Chapter 11 of Fried & Jarden's *Field Arithmetic*. As a "motto" for pseudo algebraically closed (PAC) fields, they say they are fields $K$ such that "each nonempty variety defined over $K$ has a $K$-rational point". No mention of absolute irreducibility is made at this point.

My issue is: how does this differ to algebraically closed fields? In particular, considering one variable polynomials, demanding that each $f(x) \in K[x]$ has a zero in $K$ would surely satisfy the standard ACF axiomatization?

Comment: If I remember correctly, that is just a terminology issue. In that book, "variety defined over $K$" includes "absolutely irreducible". See section 10.2 where this is explained, although maybe not very clearly.

Comment: Yes, I think this is it exactly. Thank you.

Comment: In any case I've seen several times pseudo-X in model theory to mean "satisfying all sentences that hold all for all structures in X". In this respect the terminology is confusing.